# (2/2) ErrorException Property [CampaignID] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

when i have this in my controller:

```
$campaign = Campaign::where('CampaignID',$id)->get();
```

and return it in this way in my controller:

```
return view('campaign.donateCampaign',compact('campaign'));
```

How do I call its datas into my blade? cause i can't call it in this way **value="{{ $campaign->CampaignID }}"** . Is there any other way to call it? please help

i kept getting this error :

> (2/2) ErrorException Property [CampaignID] does not exist on this
>   collection instance.

My Controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OKI7.png)

My Blade:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmnOd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `get()` gives you a collection of objects, not a single one, you should modify your code.

> Use `->first()` instead of `->get()`

This will give you a single object with required properties.